# How to remove ** from my cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel file having keys and values. The values contain `**`.

How can I remove these asterisks when for them Find and Replace does not work?

I am using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Asterisk `*` is often a wildcard. To find a literal `*` it is necessary to escape the character, for Excel you use `~`.

For example, to search for `*`, you would use `~*`.

Same as if you were searching for `?`, you would use `~?`.

So to answer your question and search for `**`, you would use `~*~*`.

From: [Find or replace text and numbers on a worksheet](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/find-or-replace-text-and-numbers-on-a-worksheet-HP010342525.aspx)

Comment: @random: Could you please confirm why my edit was reversed? As per [THIS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139569/valid-answer-deleted-and-changed-to-comment) I was advised to ensure that I posted more than just a mere link...

Comment: A whole page as an image means you still don't have any actual content to "read". It's all trapped in an image. The "no links as answer alone" means you need to include at least an applicable portion of the source/website/link on how it answers the problem, not just a link to read more.

Comment: Comparing the two original versions of both answers, this one leaves out what the OP should type in, until another user edited in the actual answer. Again, **do not screenshot a whole webpage and paste that as an answer**. You cannot search text in images and you should always reframe answers instead of just copy-paste. Adding a link shows where you got the information from if you referenced it elsewhere

Comment: If you would like to ask the community what they think of taking a screenshot of a webpage and saying that's an answer, do feel free to ask on http://meta.superuser.com

Answer (score 7):

Try replacing `~*~*`. Single `*` characters are interpreted as wildcards, as are `?` characters. The `~` before it 'escapes' these special characters.